# How do i install PolyML on my command prompt

Tags: windows, cmd, sml, polyml

I wold like to use visual studio ti programm in SML and I don't know how to install Poly on the command prompt

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to have make installed ( cmake  in windows )

try to look at install section in the [git repo](http://%20https://github.com/polyml/polyml#platforms-and-installation)
or use the site install [manual](https://www.polyml.org/download.html)